# Javascript Tic-tac-toe Game

Tags: javascript, html, tic-tac-toe

everyone!
Yesterday, I started making a tic-tac-toe game for a website I wanted to make. After about 10 hours of working on it, I came up with about 150 lines of code just for the simple game. As usual when I make a large chunk of code, something, which I can't identify, went wrong. My whole entire code didn't work. Because of the large chunk of code, I copy pasted my code into a jsFiddle project, url shown below. My question is: can I use arrays or something of that type to lessen the number of if statements and redundancies? If anyone one can also help me create a faster, more efficient, code, I would be very thankful. Thanks in advance!

jsfiddle.net/justinpchang/3L6tp/

Comment: If you're looking at improving code quality in general, you could go here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would suggest you to ***NEVER*** write your id tag that way you do (`id  = "something"`). Proper way: `id="something"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have something like this :

```
/* This represents the current game, declare it upon starting a new game*/
var board = [['-','-','-'],['-','-','-'],['-','-','-']];

function notTaken(board,row,col) {
    return (board[row][col] == '-');
}

function hasX(board,row,col) {
    return (board[row][col] == 'x');
} // have a similar function for O
```

This eliminates a lot of redundancy in your code. Also, with HTML5 you can add custom attributes to your div elements which will specify the row and column of the cell. So top-mid div for example would have attributes "data-row" and "data-col" and values 0 and 1 respectively. I think the attribute names have to start with "data-" but I'm not sure.

Oh and one other thing: Never compare booleans to true or false, it is redundant. instead of doing:
    (some_bool != false)
Just do:
    (some_bool)

Since booleans can only be true or false anyways. Similarly:
    (some_bool == false)
Can just be written as:
    !(some_bool)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried running it through [JSLint](http://jslint.com/)? It validates your code and looks for potential bugs. It will also hurt your feelings.

Comment: Up-vote for your humorous and truthful answer.

Comment: half of the problems on jslint was spaces that their compiler didn't like.

Comment: @justinpchang you can select which rules you want, disable whitespace checking if you prefer messy whitespace.

Comment: JSHint is more forgiving/configurable. I like JSLint though :)

Comment: JSLint marked everything from the jQuery library as an error

Comment: @justinpchang Fix the errors in your jsfiddle and click on the "JSHint" button. Its suggestions are a bit more reasonable.

Comment: @justinpchang You gotta learn how to use it :) JSLint has no idea what jQuery is, so you have to declare it in the globals textbox, or annotate it properly

Comment: ok thanks ian i did it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

By copy/pasting code all over the place you defeat the purpose of programming... Try to find a pattern in your code, and make functions to do the same thing with different variables. Then it will be more readable and extensible.